# How to reset the Password for Web UI of Bacula

Tags: rhel, bacula

My colleague is on vacation and I need to configure bacula but I don't know the password for user. So I need to reset the password for user.

What is the way to reset the password?

Comment: Login as root, and use `su` to beccome the user. No need to reset the password. If you don't know the root password. ask the system administrator.

Comment: Oh yes got it, root user working...